# Chrome modern UI windows 8 disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

My Chrome modern UI in Windows 8 has disappeared. I can't find it on the store either. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open Chrome in Desktop mode.
2. From the Settings menu, select **Relaunch Chrome in Windows 8 mode.**
   [image]
3. If Chrome is already set as your default browser it will launch in Windows 8 mode, otherwise Windows will ask you to select a default browser. If you choose Chrome, it will launch using the Modern UI.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have set another browser as your default browser.

Answer (score 2):

Did you unpin it from Start?

Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, find **Google Chrome** in the list of programs, right-click it, then choose **Pin to Start**.

[image]